# Macro within macro with malloc leads to runtime error?

Tags: c, macros, runtime-error, libc

I have this piece of code

```
#define MZERO(a, s)  (a==NULL ? NULL : memset(a, 0, sizeof(a)*s))
#define MALLOC(t)    (t*)malloc(sizeof(t))
#define CALLOC(t, s) s<=0 ? NULL : (t*)MZERO(calloc(sizeof(t), s), s)
```

which basicaly lets me get around the ridiculous amount of boilerplate C requires for malloc et al. `MALLOC` and `MZERO` run as intended however at runtime CALLOC causes

```
malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *)
&((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2]))- __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) &&
old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof
(struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *
(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end &
pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

I've been using these macros in their "simple" format, like `MALLOC`, and recently decided to combine them. Note that the same error appears even without the triadic operator.

The only references to that error message I've found are some [mailing list](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/434640?do=post_view_threaded) posts which don't contain a solution. I think I've combined them in the past without any problems but I'm not really sure. In any case my libgc version is `2.13-38+deb7u1` with GCC `4.7.2`

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You need more parentheses in the CALLOC macro for safety: `#define CALLOC(t, s) (s<=0 ? NULL : (t*)MZERO(calloc(sizeof(t), s), s))`, adding a set of parentheses around the whole expression. I'd be happier with parentheses around the appearances of `s`.  For example, `CALLOC(int, x&0x7)` would be misinterpreted because of the lack of parentheses around the `s` in `s<=0`.  Where `s` is used as an argument, I think you're OK, but where it is used in an expression, you are not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You make a valid point although I don't think I'd ever use an expression like this... Parentheses added anyway. Cheers

Comment: `#define MALLOC(t)    (t*)malloc(sizeof(t))`   , lol

Comment: @MattMcNabb is that a good lol or should I be worried?

Comment: The `(t*)` bit is a waste of space .. you are worried about "ridiculous boilerplate" but it is of your own devising.  Just go `Foo *foo = malloc( sizeof *foo );`

Comment: @MattMcNabb gcc used to complain if I didn't do the typecast, but then again I've never tried the other way. I also assume you would've told me eventually even if I hadn't prompted you ;)

Comment: If it complains, then fix by doing `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, don't use macros like this. You're just entering a world of pain.

Remember macros are a text expansion performed by the pre-processor. Let's pretend we're the pre-processor, with two of your macros...

```
#define MZERO(a, s)  (a==NULL ? NULL : memset(a, 0, sizeof(a)*s))
#define CALLOC(t, s) s<=0 ? NULL : (t*)MZERO(calloc(sizeof(t), s), s)
```

Now, the part `MZERO(calloc(sizeof(t), s), s)` will expand like this:-

```
(calloc(sizeof(t), s)==NULL ? NULL : memset(calloc(sizeof(t), s), 0, sizeof(calloc(sizeof(t), s))*s))
```

I think you didn't really want `calloc` called three times. I can list a slew of other potential issues because you aren't correctly wrapping each param in brackets within the macros, but really, enough: Don't abuse macros like this.

Comment: I didn't realize that. I guess the "simple" form was the best after all eh? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such asserts message would appear when the program has some memory corruption scenario. You may want to use Valgrind. Your CALLOC MACRO is also not correct in the sense it is actually clearing memory twice so it should be

```
#define CALLOC(t, s) s<=0 ? NULL : (t*)MZERO(calloc(sizeof(t), s), s)
```

should be

```
   #define CALLOC(t, s) s<=0 ? NULL : (t*)calloc(sizeof(*t), s)
```

Comment: I always thought calloc simply called malloc in the background, never realized it also initialized memory, so +1 on that. I did as you suggest and placed MZERO around malloc instead. Everything works fine.